# Control Windows audio volume from PHP or web UI

Tags: php, windows, batch-file, audio

I'd like to know if there is any way of changing the Windows system volume from a web site, either PHP or batch files being run by PHP or something like that.

I basically want to be able to change the volume of my Media server from a laptop or iPad, and preferably with PHP /batch/web, not an external application.

Any help or advice would be appreciated.

Comment: http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html <- CLI tool to control various stuff incl. system volume level, mute etc.

Comment: very helpful! thanks! Could I use exec("nircmd.exe changesysvolume -5000"); to execute through php? Cant get access to my server now to test...

Comment: It is my understanding that `exec`  works exactly like you outlined it. Give it a go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your php is running on the server you want to control, you might try PHPs system and exec commands with a little command line utility like [nircmd](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html).

Answer (score 0):

You could always run [VNC](http://www.realvnc.com/index.html) on the machine you want to control and use a vnc client from the laptop, ipad, iphone, or a lot of other devices.